# How to Open a Website on success response from server in android?

Tags: android

I am developing a functionality in which if server response in success then open URL. But when opening website gives error

```
"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com }
```

How can I resolve that?

here is my code

```
public void getResponse() throws JSONException {
    m_szDealActionUrl = m_oResponseobject.getString("dealactionUrl");
}

public void conditions() throws JSONException {
    if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(m_szDealActionUrl);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of m_szDealActionUrl?

Comment: add the `http://` to your `m_szDealActionUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should properly fill the `Uri` string (in this case `m_szDealActionUrl`) to show that you want to open a webpage so `m_szDealActionUrl` should be `"http://www.google.com"` instead of `"www.google.com"`

Comment: is there any permission in menifest regarding this

Comment: Give this permission in your menifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />